# On Change event inside Typeahead is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to check if the Onchange event inside typeahead is working or not, but apparently, it isn't. Here is the code:

```
class Search extends Component {
 state = {
      searchName: ''
}

handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({searchName: event.target.value})
    console.log('Name Change: ', event.target.value);
}

render() {
    return (
      <div class="form-group">
                    <Typeahead
                        id="basic-example"
                        options={this.state.hcpName}
                        placeholder="Search by Name..."
                        onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                    />
                </div>
)}
 }
```

What's the problem with this code? When I type in the field, I do not see anything in the console.

Comment: try arrow function for handleNameChange

Comment: Tried, not working. Wrote like this: handleNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({searchName: event.target.value})
        console.log('Name Change: ', event.target.value);
    }

Comment: Are you getting any error ? which version are you using ?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error as such.

Comment: but onChange is prop to the the Typehead component there is some error in ur Type head component because onChange is used for input tags

Comment: Is it because I'm using Typeahead? When I tried the same thing in an input field of another component, it worked...

Comment: yes there it is because of Type head

Comment: @Om Fuke Typeahead is part of 'react-bootstrap-typeahead' which I imported. I imported like this: import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

Comment: check how to use it in class component here is one example in hooks [Typehead](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-typeahead-basic-example-9jq9jyzmry?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229350/discussion-between-shridhark-and-om-fuke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to directly change the state instead of calling a function. Here is how:

```
class Search extends Component {
state = {
  searchName: ''
}


 render() {
return (
  <div class="form-group">
                <Typeahead
                    id="basic-example"
                    options={this.state.hcpName}
                    placeholder="Search by Name..."
                    onInputChange={(searchName) => this.setState({searchName})}
                />
            </div>
    )}
  }
```

Basically, I used onInputChange instead of onChange and then changed the state directly inside of typeahead.

Comment: Note that `onChange` and `onInputChange` serve 2 different purposes. The former is called whenever the typeahead selections changes, and passes an array of selections as the argument. The latter fires in response to user entry in the input. See https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/API.md